# Oracle PL/SQL Trigger to limit orders per customer

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Just working on creating a little trigger. What I'm wanting this trigger to do is make sure that a customer can only have 10 orders in the placed order table at one current time. Don't ask why my client wants this it seems silly to me ha.

But basically the trigger is on the placed order table, I'm currently selecting a DISTINCT COUNT on the customer_ID and placing it into a v_count VARIABLE.

```
IF v_count < 10 INSERT INTO placed_order
ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('you have 10 or more orders processing please wait')
END if
END
```

That is the basic jist of the code but it just won't run I can show the full code if anyone would like?

HERE IS THE CODE - sorry i don't know how to use SQLFiddle right now.

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_order_limit
     BEFORE INSERT
     ON placed_order
     FOR EACH ROW
     DECLARE
     v_count number;
     BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FK1_customer_id) FROM placed_order into v_count;
     if v_count < 10 then
     INSERT INTO placed_order
     (order_id,  order_date, delivery_date, FK1_customer_id, FK2_employee_id,        FK3_Order_type_id)
     VALUES
     (:NEW.order_id, :NEW.order_date, :NEW.delivery_date, :NEW.FK1_customer_id,     :NEW.FK2employee_id, :NEW.FK3_order_type_id);
     ELSE
     v_count > 10 then
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You currently have 10 or more orders processing.');
     end if;
     end;
```

When i run the script in oracle i get
Error at line 4: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Thanks a lot
Richard

Comment: Yes, please add the full code, and if possible create an [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) showing the problem.

Comment: Also what does "won't run" mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: triggers can not be safely used to implement this kind of logic (think about concurrent inserts..the trigger misses them and will allow that rule to be violated). you need to control this in an API (serialize it) or a materialized view can do it too.

Comment: You should never place business logic/rules in the database. If you absolutely must, you should use a CONSTRAINT for this, rather than a TRIGGER.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I disagree. The database is the most sensible place where you should check such constraints, since it cannot be circumvented (if you place such checks in your application logic and someone accesses the data directly, your checks will be useless).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt I suppose it depends on the other requirements. If you want a blanket rule that says "All customers can never, ever have more than 10 orders" then sure. But maybe you want to differentiate between "Regular" and "Premium" customers? Soon, your CONSTRAINT become non-trivial and unmaintainable.

Also, you should really try to design your software in such a way that "End users obtain unrestricted access to the underlying datastore" is not a scenario you need to take special considerations for.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I agree wholeheartedly that end users shouldn't have unrestricted access to the database, but IME, even DBAs and developers tend to make mistakes sometimes :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if your trigger didn't have a syntax error, it wouldn't work: It would just output the "Can't have more than 10 orders" message and the insert would still go ahead; moreover, if it passed the test, you'd be put into a loop of inserts. You need to make it throw an exception, in the event of too many records, and your application needs to catch that, and do nothing if it passes the test.

As for the error, I think the problem is with this line:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FK1_customer_id) FROM placed_order into v_count;
```

It should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT FK1_customer_id) into v_count FROM placed_order;
```

However, this query is wrong anyway: It will return the number of unique customers that have made orders. What you're looking for is:

```
select count(order_id) into v_count from placed_order where fk1_customer_id = :new.fk1_customer_id
```

Presuming that `order_id` has a uniqueness constraint; which seems likely! Anyway, therefore, your trigger code should be something like:

```
create or replace trigger trg_order_limit
before insert on placed_order for each row
declare
  v_count number;
begin
  -- Get current order count
  select count(order_id)
  into   v_count
  from   placed_order
  where  fk1_customer_id = :new.fk1_customer_id;

  -- Raise exception if there are too many
  if v_count >= 10 then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'You currently have 10 or more orders processing.');
  end if;
end;
```

However, as per [@DazzaL's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15546074/oracle-pl-sql-trigger-to-limit-orders-per-customer#comment22027392_15546074), this approach probably isn't a good idea.

---

**EDIT** Sudden realisation that your query to count the number of orders per client is totally wrong. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for that its helped me greatly. I agree totally with you both its not good practice to be creating this and i said in the start its a requirement of the client maybe i'll show him this thread and try make him see sense ha.
Again thank you for your help and time

Comment: Updated my answer because the query to count orders by customer ID was really wrong :P

Comment: Oh yeah just noticed too ha thanks for the help tho anyway. When i try insert a row now which should fail it does but returns a nasty oracle error
ORA-20000: You currently have 10 or more orders processing.
ORA-06512: at "C3283535.TRG_ORDER_LIMIT", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C3283535.TRG_ORDER_LIMIT'

Is this changeable with error handling?

Comment: That's the idea!! As I say, your application needs to catch that error -- if/when it occurs -- and report it back to the client in some meaningful way.